# finding the interpolated values of an empirical probability distribution

Tags: computational-statistics, scipy, distributions, numerical-integration, numpy

I have an empirical probability function $p(z)$. In the first column $z$ and the second column contains $p(z)$ values. The data is given as following :

**data.cat**

```
+0.01234 +0.002816
+0.03693 +0.003265
+0.06152 +0.003551
+0.08611 +0.006612
+0.1107 +0.008898
+0.1353 +0.01041
+0.1599 +0.01269
+0.1845 +0.01404
+0.2091 +0.01616
+0.2336 +0.01657
+0.2582 +0.01865
+0.2828 +0.01951
+0.3074 +0.02024
+0.332 +0.02131
+0.3566 +0.0222
+0.3812 +0.02306
+0.4058 +0.02241
+0.4304 +0.02347
+0.4549 +0.02461
+0.4795 +0.02306
+0.5041 +0.02298
+0.5287 +0.02212
+0.5533 +0.02392
+0.5779 +0.02118
+0.6025 +0.02359
+0.6271 +0.024
+0.6517 +0.02196
+0.6762 +0.02155
+0.7008 +0.02314
+0.7254 +0.02037
+0.75 +0.02065
+0.7746 +0.0211
+0.7992 +0.02037
+0.8238 +0.0198
+0.8484 +0.01984
+0.873 +0.01959
+0.8976 +0.01869
+0.9221 +0.01873
+0.9467 +0.01861
+0.9713 +0.01714
+0.9959 +0.01739
+1.02 +0.01678
+1.045 +0.01633
+1.07 +0.01624
+1.094 +0.01543
+1.119 +0.01494
+1.143 +0.01547
+1.168 +0.01445
+1.193 +0.01384
+1.217 +0.01339
+1.242 +0.01384
+1.266 +0.01298
+1.291 +0.0109
+1.316 +0.0122
+1.34 +0.0111
+1.365 +0.0109
+1.389 +0.009592
+1.414 +0.01114
+1.439 +0.0111
+1.463 +0.009061
+1.488 +4.082e-05
```

I have to compute the following integral using the empirical probability density by some kind of interpolation:

$$\int_0^{\chi_l}\mathrm{d}\chi\Bigg[\int_{\chi}^{\chi_s}\mathrm{d}\chi'\big[p(z)\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}\chi}\big]_{z=z(\chi')}\frac{\chi'-\chi}{\chi'}\Bigg]\frac{\chi}{a}=\\\int_0^{\chi_l}\mathrm{d}\chi\Bigg[\int_{\chi}^{\chi_s}\mathrm{d}\chi'p(\chi')\frac{\chi'-\chi}{\chi'}\Bigg]\frac{\chi}{a}$$

where $p(z)\mathrm{d}z=p(\chi)\mathrm{d}\chi$ and $\chi$ is defined as $$\mathrm{d}\chi=\frac{dz}{\bigg[0.3(1+z)^3+0.7\bigg]^{0.5}}$$ and $a$ is given as $a=\frac{1}{1+z}$. I am wondering how I could compute this integral?

Comment: The focus of this question appears to be on how to compute the PDF of a transformed variable.  Why not read some of our threads on this by [searching the site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=pdf%20transformation)?

Comment: @whuber I need this probability to use as an integrand of an integral and I don't know what is the best way to compute it in python?

Comment: The theoretical work is of interest here, but the Python details are not on topic.  Nevertheless, exactly what would you mean by "best"?

Comment: @whuber First of all I am wondering whether the way I have suggested to find the probability density function for the changed variable is correct or not? Then what is the best approach to compute it from an initial empirical density function?

Comment: I am sympathetic to this question, but--once again--may we know what you mean by "best"? Are you interested in speed, accuracy, ease of programming?  If accuracy, then how should it be measured? What is the original reason for the interpolation anyway?

Comment: @whuber I am looking for the most accurate of course and the second priority is to be programmed easily. I assume interpolation would be a good approach and very close to the real distribution compared to any analytical formula that might be available.

Comment: @whuber of course I am throwing some random thoughts and doesn't seem to be practical in my application.

Comment: @whuber I have updated my question! I need to compute the abovementioned and I don't have any clue how it should combine this empirical probability function with the rest of integrand.

Comment: What about trying to fit a spline to the log-density?